# Using streaming HTTP chunked responses in Playframework

Tags: java, playframework, akka, akka-stream, playframework-2.6

I am trying to build a REST API in Java using Play framework 2.6 that will send responses to the client in chunks. In order to do so, I am following the chunked response builder example as per [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaStream#chunked-responses) of Play HTTP Response streaming.

In the example (also copied below), after sending the chunks, it is closing the source. How to keep the source opened and use the sourceActor to continue sending more messages after some processing? This processing could be happening in some other actor which has access to the sourceActor.

```
public Result index() {
// Prepare a chunked text stream
Source<ByteString, ?> source = Source.<ByteString>actorRef(256, OverflowStrategy.dropNew())
    .mapMaterializedValue(sourceActor -> {
        sourceActor.tell(ByteString.fromString("kiki"), null);
        sourceActor.tell(ByteString.fromString("foo"), null);
        sourceActor.tell(ByteString.fromString("bar"), null);
        sourceActor.tell(new Status.Success(NotUsed.getInstance()), null);
        return NotUsed.getInstance();
    });
// Serves this stream with 200 OK
return ok().chunked(source);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`BroadcastHub`](https://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/2.5/akka/stream/javadsl/BroadcastHub.html):

```
Pair<ActorRef, Source<ByteString, NotUsed>> source =
  Source.<ByteString>actorRef(256, OverflowStrategy.dropNew())
    .toMat(BroadcastHub.of(ByteString.class), Keep.both())
    .run(materializer);

ActorRef sourceActor = source.first();
Source<ByteString, NotUsed> matSource = source.second();
```

Messages sent to the materialized actor are emitted downstream, and you can use the materialized source to complete the method (note that there is no backpressure with this approach):

```
sourceActor.tell(ByteString.fromString("kiki"), ActorRef.noSender());
// send more messages to sourceActor...

return ok().chunked(matSource);
```

You might need to use [`keepAlive`](https://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/2.5/akka/stream/javadsl/Source.html#keepAlive-java.time.Duration-akka.japi.function.Creator-) to inject messages into the stream to keep it open.